# CSS button hover effect not working

Tags: html, css

i am trying to do a hover effect with css something super simply, but i'm over looking something, im trying to have the user to be able to hover over a button and have a light shade of white with an opacity applied. But whenever i am doing so my border of the button disappears, I know this because I am targeting the button element. So how does this work without targeting the button element and still keeping the border from not going away. My jsfiddle link is below.

https://jsfiddle.net/bvcxtds/6Lr501g1/

and here is my markup

```
<button><a>SIGN UP</a></button>
```

and my css

```
button {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}
button > a {
    color: white;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    background: white;
}
body {
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: And shouldn't it be ".button", with a period before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opacity applies to the entire element, not only the background. The border doesn't actually disappear, it becomes the same color as the background.

Use a background color with an alpha value instead:

```
button:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lr501g1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'background' for 'color':

```
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: The text is already white, and that doesn't keep the opacity from affecting the border.

Comment: @Guffa is correct, but thanks for helping me out tho! appreciate it.

Comment: True, I dont understand the question.:P

Answer (score 0):

small changes  a and button

```
button {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}
button a{
    color:#FFF
}



button:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    background: white;
}
button:hover a{
    color: #060606;
  opacity: 1;
}
body {
    background: black;
}
```

[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperH/jy8oua01/)